# Array of Pipes AND redirections AND signals

Tags: c, arrays, pipe, signals

I have a "theoric" problem to solve,

i have a CTRL program that will be executed with x arguments (./CTRL X1 X2 XN).

Each of x is an program to execute and all of them give a "ok" to standard output demonstrating that are alive every 3s. If the CTRL program doesn't receive the "ok" it should kill the x program and print the time it executed.

when they are all done, the CTRL ends.

I manage (i think) to create the x programs, the pipes and redirection, but, how can i check that its getting a response every 3s and count it?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int r,i;
int pn = argc;
int filhos[pn];
int fd[pn][2];
int time[pn][1];

//start the pn process and redirect from stdout do pipe
for (i=1 ; i<=pn;i++;) {
    r=fork();
    filhos[i] = getpid();
    pipe(fd[i]);
    if (r==0) {
        close(fd[i][0]);
        dup2(fd[i][1],1); //redirect stdout to pipe
        close(fd[i][1]);
        execlp(argv[i],argv[i],NULL);
    }
    else { 
    //how to check every 3s to confirm its printing the "ok" ?
    open(fd[i][0]);
    wait(status); //should be a while(1) ?
    //check if its receiving the "ok" and kill the process if not
    kill(filhos[i],SIGUSR1);
    //print the time it took - how to now the time passed?
    printf("process %s has terminated over %i seconds",argv[i],time[i]);
    }
}
//when all of them stops
return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

ok, to get the time passed i can use the

```
 time_t start_t, end_t;
 double diff_t;
 time(&start_t);
 time(&end_t);
 diff_t = difftime(end_t, start_t);
```

Comment: If you want the parent to be able to communicate with the children via the pipes, then each child's pipe must be created *before* that child is forked, by the parent.  If you create the pipe after, then parent and child do it separately, and they get unrelated pipes.  Moreover, the parent does not separately open its ends of the pipes -- the `pipe()` function delivers them already open.

Comment: After each fork, the parent should close the write end of the pipe, and the child should close the read ends of *all* the pipes creates so far, so that each end of each pipe is open in exactly one process, no more.

Comment: If your child processes are supposed to run concurrently, then the `wait()` and `kill()` do not belong in the loop in which you spawn the children.  Moreover, if you successfully `wait()` on a child process then you do not need to `kill()` that process -- it is already dead.

Comment: Since you have pipes with which to communicate with the children, and you don't necessarily know which to read next at any given point, you probably want the `select()` function to multiplex the I/O.  Additionally, that has a timeout option which will help you.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ok, i can change the pipe not oppening it.

the part of the wait/kill is because i don't know how to check if the process is printing out the "ok" every 3s, when it does not, it should be killed.

will read on the select() option